# Python LDAP: Get all group memberships recursively

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

Using Python LDAP, how do I get all the groups a user is a member of, recursively.

For example if a user is member of the group `"Zurich"`, which is part of the group `"Switzerland"`, I would like to receive `["Zurich", "Switzerland"]`

Comment: You have to write the code. Start with a stack and push the user DN. Then while the stack isn't empty, pop the first element and push all the groups it is a member of. Repeat until empty. All the groups will have been encountered during this process, i.e. everything you popped except the first one was a group.

Comment: Could you give an example in code? Also, I was told Active Directory has a direction LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN that would retrieve the memberships recursively, meaning I would not have to make multiple queries.